# setuptools package_dir copies into wrong folder

Tags: python, setuptools, setup.py

currently i'm triying to package a python package with setuptools, cmake and the corresponding native libraries. The build step is running as expected. However, when i'm trying to install the package, I'm getting some unexpected locations, which are displayed below.
So I've got the following project structure:

```
project
│   setup.py   
│
└───mypackage
│   │   __init__.py
│   │   some more files...
│   │
│   └───subpackage
│       │   __init__.py
│       │   some more files...
│   
└───src
    │   example1.cpp
    │   example2.cpp
    │   some more files...
```

everything compiles fine, but if I run `python setup.py install`, it will install the following structure:
Look out for the **all compiled dlls** line

```
mypackage-<version>-py3.9-win-amd64.egg
│
└───mypackage
│   │   __init__.py
│   │   some more files...
│   │
│   └───subpackage
│       │   __init__.py
│       │   some more files...
└── all compiled dlls
```

what I would expect is this:

```
mypackage-<version>-py3.9-win-amd64.egg
│
└───mypackage
    │   __init__.py
    │   some more files...
    └── **all compiled dlls**
    └───subpackage
       │   __init__.py
       │   some more files...
```

My setup.py looks like this:

```
[code to build]
setup(
    name="mypackage",
    version="1.0.0",
    packages=['mypackage','mypackage.subpackage'],
    author=...,
    author_email=...,
    description=...,
    license=...,
    keywords=...,
    url=...,
    tests_require=[
       ...
    ],
    package_data={
        'mypackage': ['lib/*.*', 'lib/*/*/*', 'share/*/*'],
    },
    test_suite=...,
    ext_modules=[CMakeExtension("mypackage")],
    cmdclass={"build_ext": CMakeBuild},
    zip_safe=False
)
```

Is there anyway to tell setup-tools to copy the package_data files to the mypackage folder?
I thought that the `'mypackage': ['lib/*.*', 'lib/*/*/*', 'share/*/*'],` would do that. Or do I have to write my own logic to accomplish that?

Comment: Might need some more details, since I'm not familiar with `CMakeExtension`.  `package_data` usually assumes it's installing files that live in the package directory in the source tree as well (so the paths you gave would be relative to `my_package/`

Comment: The CMakeExtensions are from pybind-example :https://github.com/pybind/cmake_example/blob/master/setup.py

I've used most of the setup.py code but nothing else from the repo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay. Nevermind. I've just figured it out:

I had the https://github.com/pybind/cmake_example/blob/ce0ea77878522a85da0be13cf9e425626d05827e/setup.py#L46 `DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY` specified. So all libraries will be under this directory. `'mypackage': ['lib/*.*', 'lib/*/*/*', 'share/*/*']`  this line had no effect at all.

So with adding `mypackage` to https://github.com/pybind/cmake_example/blob/ce0ea77878522a85da0be13cf9e425626d05827e/setup.py#L30 (`ext_dir`) would solve my problem

Adding the code from the links below, in case they should no longer be accessible at some point.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import os
import re
import subprocess
import sys

from setuptools import setup, Extension
from setuptools.command.build_ext import build_ext

# Convert distutils Windows platform specifiers to CMake -A arguments
PLAT_TO_CMAKE = {
    "win32": "Win32",
    "win-amd64": "x64",
    "win-arm32": "ARM",
    "win-arm64": "ARM64",
}


# A CMakeExtension needs a sourcedir instead of a file list.
# The name must be the _single_ output extension from the CMake build.
# If you need multiple extensions, see scikit-build.
class CMakeExtension(Extension):
    def __init__(self, name, sourcedir=""):
        Extension.__init__(self, name, sources=[])
        self.sourcedir = os.path.abspath(sourcedir)


class CMakeBuild(build_ext):
    def build_extension(self, ext):
        extdir = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(self.get_ext_fullpath(ext.name)))

        # required for auto-detection of auxiliary "native" libs
        if not extdir.endswith(os.path.sep):
            extdir += os.path.sep

        cfg = "Debug" if self.debug else "Release"

        # CMake lets you override the generator - we need to check this.
        # Can be set with Conda-Build, for example.
        cmake_generator = os.environ.get("CMAKE_GENERATOR", "")

        # Set Python_EXECUTABLE instead if you use PYBIND11_FINDPYTHON
        # EXAMPLE_VERSION_INFO shows you how to pass a value into the C++ code
        # from Python.
        cmake_args = [
            "-DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY={}".format(extdir),
            "-DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE={}".format(sys.executable),
            "-DEXAMPLE_VERSION_INFO={}".format(self.distribution.get_version()),
            "-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE={}".format(cfg),  # not used on MSVC, but no harm
        ]
        build_args = []

        if self.compiler.compiler_type != "msvc":
            # Using Ninja-build since it a) is available as a wheel and b)
            # multithreads automatically. MSVC would require all variables be
            # exported for Ninja to pick it up, which is a little tricky to do.
            # Users can override the generator with CMAKE_GENERATOR in CMake
            # 3.15+.
            if not cmake_generator:
                try:
                    import ninja  # noqa: F401

                    cmake_args += ["-GNinja"]
                except ImportError:
                    pass

        else:

            # Single config generators are handled "normally"
            single_config = any(x in cmake_generator for x in {"NMake", "Ninja"})

            # CMake allows an arch-in-generator style for backward compatibility
            contains_arch = any(x in cmake_generator for x in {"ARM", "Win64"})

            # Specify the arch if using MSVC generator, but only if it doesn't
            # contain a backward-compatibility arch spec already in the
            # generator name.
            if not single_config and not contains_arch:
                cmake_args += ["-A", PLAT_TO_CMAKE[self.plat_name]]

            # Multi-config generators have a different way to specify configs
            if not single_config:
                cmake_args += [
                    "-DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_{}={}".format(cfg.upper(), extdir)
                ]
                build_args += ["--config", cfg]

        if sys.platform.startswith("darwin"):
            # Cross-compile support for macOS - respect ARCHFLAGS if set
            archs = re.findall(r"-arch (\S+)", os.environ.get("ARCHFLAGS", ""))
            if archs:
                cmake_args += ["-DCMAKE_OSX_ARCHITECTURES={}".format(";".join(archs))]

        # Set CMAKE_BUILD_PARALLEL_LEVEL to control the parallel build level
        # across all generators.
        if "CMAKE_BUILD_PARALLEL_LEVEL" not in os.environ:
            # self.parallel is a Python 3 only way to set parallel jobs by hand
            # using -j in the build_ext call, not supported by pip or PyPA-build.
            if hasattr(self, "parallel") and self.parallel:
                # CMake 3.12+ only.
                build_args += ["-j{}".format(self.parallel)]

        if not os.path.exists(self.build_temp):
            os.makedirs(self.build_temp)

        subprocess.check_call(
            ["cmake", ext.sourcedir] + cmake_args, cwd=self.build_temp
        )
        subprocess.check_call(
            ["cmake", "--build", "."] + build_args, cwd=self.build_temp
        )


# The information here can also be placed in setup.cfg - better separation of
# logic and declaration, and simpler if you include description/version in a file.
setup(
    name="cmake_example",
    version="0.0.1",
    author="Dean Moldovan",
    author_email="dean0x7d@gmail.com",
    description="A test project using pybind11 and CMake",
    long_description="",
    ext_modules=[CMakeExtension("cmake_example")],
    cmdclass={"build_ext": CMakeBuild},
    zip_safe=False,
    extras_require={"test": ["pytest"]},
)
```

Comment: I was going to say, you normally never have to do anything special to ensure that compiled extension modules are installed correctly, but I wasn't sure if there wasn't some oddity about the cmake-based tools you're using.

Comment: yep. First time creating a python package. compelety overlooked that.

Comment: Congrats!  It looks like a pretty non-trivial build too.